# Add section after 4 posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to add a section of text after 4 posts on my index.php page? And then again at 8 posts.

I've only got a simple loop at the moment and haven't known where to start! Thanks

```
<?php
get_header();
?>

    <main id="primary" class="site-main">

        <div class="intro">
            <h1 class="intro-text">Hi! I’m an Aussie illustrator living in London.</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="post-grid grid">
            <div class="grid-sizer">
                <?php
                if ( have_posts() ) :


                    /* Start the Loop */
                    while ( have_posts() ) :
                        the_post();

                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-thumb', get_post_type() );

                    endwhile;

                    the_posts_navigation();

                else :

                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

                endif;
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>


    </main><!-- #main -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code which uses the modulus division operator that checks for the Nth iteration.

**EDIT:** I moved $counter++; to the top of the while loop. It should work properly now.

```
<?php
  if ( have_posts() ) :
    /* Start the Loop */
    while ( have_posts() ) :
    $counter++;
    the_post();

    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-thumb', get_post_type() );

    // Check for 4th iteration in the loop
    if ($counter % 4 == 0) {
      echo 'YOUR TEXT HERE';
    }
    endwhile;

    the_posts_navigation();

else :

  get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

endif;
?>
```

Comment: Almost! Though it seems to add text to the first and fifth posts rather than the 4th.

Comment: Then please change the $counter++; position to just after while. I will edit my code now accordingly

Comment: Happy to help :)